# Json Java Data Binding for multiple POJOs

Tags: jackson, jackson-databind

Is it possible to parse a JSON containing multiple Objects with the ObjectMapper? For example

```
{
  "employee": {
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "age": 30,
    "department": "sales"
  },
  "department": {
    "name": "sales",
    "company": "abcd",
    "lead": "Mr Harrison"
  },
  "company": {
    "name": "abcd",
    "location": "New York"
  }
}
```

Can I get the objects Employee, Department, Company out of that file in one single mapper run, something like:

`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List of Objects = mapper.readValue(...)`

Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider the case of

> reading numerous objects in one file separately

, without creating a dedicated wrapper POJO, this is also possible to achieve, provided that you have the information to which target object type should be mapped each of the root-level keys in the JSON.

This information can be represented in a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Class<?>> targetTypes = new HashMap<>();
targetTypes.put("employee", Employee.class);
targetTypes.put("department", Department.class);
targetTypes.put("company", Company.class);
```

The deserialization will have to be done in two steps. The first one is to transform the original JSON into a `Map<String, Object>`:

```
String json = ... // the JSON
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> parsed = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
```

The second step is to match the keys of this map with the target types and transform the values into objects:

```
List<Object> objects = parsed.entrySet().stream().map(
    (entry) -> {
      Class<?> targetClass = targetTypes.get(entry.getKey());
      return mapper.convertValue(entry.getValue(), targetClass);
    }
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `objects` list now contains

```
[
 Employee(name=John, surname=Smith, age=30, department=sales), 
 Department(name=sales, company=abcd, lead=Mr Harrison), 
 Company(name=abcd, location=New York)
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a parent object that contains the 3 objects you are looking for, and read them into that single object, then use that object to access your data.

Comment: OK, that would be kind of solution. So, there is no chance of reading numerous objects in one file separately, as I suggested?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with jackson, but I would imagine it would be more difficult. The easiest solution is to make a parent with those items inside of it, and then give your framework that 1 object type that it will be more able to understand. Jackson has to have a list of things to grab, essentially, so you'd be doing essentially the same thing. Once you have the object bound, you could then just split it out into separate objects, afterwards. For clarification, does your file have fixed objects within it? (Sorry this is so late)